# Highcharter bar chart cut off x axis label

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm doing some plot with highcharter, but have some issues with label when ploting stacked barchart whan I have only one category. When I have more than one category it works well, how can I fix that ?
Thanks

```
df <- structure(list(nom_part="BOB", id_part="565626235", fact_cada_annee="2018", ok=1), 
                row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$fact_cada_annee) %>%
  # hc_add_series(name="Autres",
  #               data = df$autres,
  #               stack = "Assets") %>%
  # hc_add_series(name="Ko",
  #               data = df$ko,
  #               stack = "Assets") %>% 
  hc_add_series(name="Ok",
                data = df$ok,
                stack = "Assets") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Evolution note cadastre par année")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the simpler `hchart` way. For my example, I use the data from [highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/hchart.html) page:

```
data(mpg,package='ggplot2')
mpgman1 <-mpg %>% count(class, year)
mpgman2 <-mpg %>% count(class, year) %>% filter(class == '2seater')
mpgman3 <-mpg %>% count(class, year) %>% filter(class =='2seater',year == 1999)
```

Now `mpgman1`, `mpgman2`, `mpgman3` are used to be plotted as follows:

```
hchart(mpgman1, "column", hcaes(x = class, y = n, group = year))%>%
 hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
```

that works also for the case when one group exists:

```
hchart(mpgman2, "column", hcaes(x = class, y = n, group = year))%>%
 hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
```

or even when one level exists:

```
 hchart(mpgman3, "column", hcaes(x = class, y = n, group = year))%>%
 hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
```