# highcharter: Fixing x-axis labels in a column chart with only one column

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have the following code to create a simple column plot and it works fine:

```
library(highcharter)
d1 <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(mean_sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = 'column') %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = d1$Species) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = d1$mean_sepal_width)
```

However, when I subset the input data such that only a single x variable exists, the x axis labels are broken:

```
d2 <- d %>% filter(Species == 'virginica')
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = 'column') %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = d2$Species) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = d2$mean_sepal_width)
```

[image]

A potential solution is offered here ([Highcharter bar chart cut off x axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474984/highcharter-bar-chart-cut-off-x-axis-label)) but I prefer not to use the hchart() function since my actual plot is a lot more complicated.

Is there a way to fix these x axis labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `d2$Species` in a list (or use `as.list`). This is a known [bug](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/438).

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = 'column') %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = as.list(d2$Species)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = d2$mean_sepal_width)
```

[image: highcharter with xaxis category]